# Use Google Go's Goroutines To Create A Bayes Network

Tags: google-app-engine, go, a-star, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I have a large dataset of philosophic arguments, each of which connect to other arguments as proof or disproof of a given statement. A root statement can have many proofs and disproofs, each of which may also have proofs and disproofs.  Statements can also be used in multiple graphs, and graphs can be analyzed under a "given context" or assumption.

I need to construct a bayesian network of related arguments, so that each node propagates influence fairly and accurately to it's connected arguments; I need to be able to calculate the probability of chains of connected nodes concurrently, with each node requiring datastore lookups that must block to get results; the process is mostly I/O bound, and my datastore connection can run asynchronously in java, go and python {google appengine}.  Once each lookup completes, it propagates the effects to all other connected nodes until the probability delta drops below a threshold of irrelevance {currently 0.1%}.  Each node of the process must calculate chains of connections, then sum up all the results across all queries to adjust validity results, with results chained outward to any connected arguments.

In order to avoid recurring infinitely, I was thinking of using an A*-like process in goroutines to propagate updates to the argument maps, with a heuristic based on compounding influence which ignores nodes once probability of influence dips below, say 0.1% .  I'd tried to set up the calculations with SQL triggers, but it got complex and messy way too fast. Then I moved to google appengine to take advantage of asynchronous nosql, and it was better, but still too slow.  I need to be run the updates fast enough to get a snappy UI, so when a user creates or votes for or against a proof or disproof, they can see the results reflected in UI immediately.

I think Go is the language of choice to support the concurrency I need, but I'm open to suggestions.  The client is a monolithic javascript app that just uses XHR and websockets to push and pull argument maps {and their updates} in real time.  I have a java prototype that can compute large chains in 10~15s, but monitoring of performance shows that most of my runtime is wasted in synchronization and overhead from ConcurrentHashMap.

If there are other highly-concurrent languages worth trying out, please let me know. I know java, python, go, ruby and scala, but will learn any language if it suits my needs.

Similarly, if there are open source implementations of huge Bayesian networks, please leave a suggestion.

Comment: An interesting application, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: Well, specifically, I want to know if there is any precedent / industry standards for computing huge Bayesian networks, and whether or not goroutines are as optimally fitted for this job as they seem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a bit difficult to tell what you are asking about. Maybe you can elaborate on your question.

Goroutines are quite cheap, and are a perfect match for modern web applications which use XHR or Websockets heavily (and other I/O bound applications which have to wait for database responses and stuff like that). Additionally, the go runtime is also able to execute those goroutines in parallel, so that Go is also a good fit for CPU bound tasks, which should take advantage of multiple cores and the speed of a natively compiled language.

But you should also keep in mind, that goroutines and channels aren't for free. They still require some amount of memory and each synchronization point (e.g. a channel send or receive) comes with its cost. That's normally not a problem, since the synchronization is, in comparison to a database query for example, extremely cheap, but it might not be suited for building efficient Bayesian networks, especially if the actual work of each goroutine / node is negligible in comparison to the synchronization overhead.

Your primary goal for every concurrent program should be to avoid shared mutability as far as possible. So a Bayesian network modeled with goroutines and channels might be a good educational example and a great way to measure the performance of Go's channel implementation, but it's probably not the best fit for your problem.

Comment: ...but better than SQL triggers, I should think.

Comment: The actual work of each node of the Bayesian network will require datastore lookups followed by computations and potentially more datastore lookups until the propagated probability drops below a threshold of irrelevance {0.1% currently}.  Each datastore lookup requires blocking, so the computations themselves are fairly cheap, but the concurrency and synchronization is rather expensive.  I have an async java prototype that can complete in ~10 seconds, a time I cannot seem to cut, even with multiple threads running multiple queries at once {java threads = too heavyweight}.

Comment: I will update the question to reflect the fact the process is mostly I/O bound; and I will implement this in go and report back any findings / performance benchmarks.